# Stub external HTTP requests in Java

Tags: java, http, mocking, stubbing

We are building a Java application which makes calls to 3rd party APIs like Facebook Graph API, Twitter API and processes data recieved. We have a problem mocking those calls in test cases. The HTTP call invocation happens in a completely different class's object (usually Java SDK provided by facebook or twitter). I come from a ruby-on-rails background, where we use stub_request in [webmock](https://github.com/bblimke/webmock) to achieve similar functionality. Is there any similar framework in Java ? Any pointers, esp. examples are highly appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use Mockito or any of Mocking framework available.

If you can change url protocol from http://facebook.com to testprotocol://facebook.com then you can also register your own URL handler e.g see http://www.webbasedprogramming.com/Java-Unleashed-Second-Edition/ch24.htm